# Applescript: Running terminal commands and Saving output

Tags: variables, terminal, applescript

So, I'm trying to write a script to remove wireless networks and their associated keychain credentials.

```
tell application "Terminal"

activate
string mywifi
set mywifi to "test"
set mywifi to  do script ("networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep -A 1 'Wi-Fi' | grep -v 'Hardware' | sed -e 's/'Device:\ '//g'")



do script "networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork $mywifi NETWORK1"
do script "security delete-generic-password NETWORK1"

delay 2

#do script "networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork $mywifi NETWORK2"
#do script "security delete-generic-password Network2"

delay2

#do script "networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork $mywifi Network3"
#do script "security delete-generic-password Network3"

delay 2

#do script "networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork $mywifi Network4"
#do script "security delete-generic-password Network4"

delay 2

#do script "networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork $mywifi Network5"

#do script "security delete-generic-password Network5"

delay 2
```

end tell
quit

Where i'm running into trouble is setting that variable with the output of that command.  The command runs in terminal, though whenever I attempt to compile it, the following error is thrown

> Syntax Error: Expected """ but found unknown token

It finds this right after /device:\ '   between the \ '
    I have not been able to figure out what is missing.  If i add " between them it just drops the terminal to >
    Straight up my first foray into applescript but not my first language. I think i've been staring at it too long.

Comment: Why do you have parentheses in this line? `set mywifi to  do script ("...")`

Comment: The line should be: `set mywifi to do shell script "networksetup -listallhardwareports  | grep -A 1 'Wi-Fi' | grep -v 'Hardware' | sed -e 's/'Device:\\ '//g'"`

Comment: Why not just do the whole lot in a `bash` script rather than invoking `bash` 11 times and doing one command each time? There is no need for any AppleScript here at all.

Comment: BTW You can shorten that kludge of a command with: `set mywifi to do shell script "networksetup -listallhardwareports  | awk '/Wi-Fi/{getline; print $2}'"`

Comment: The () were just meant to highlight.  I apologize for the confusion.  I wasn't aware bash would be able to do this for me.  I assumed applescript would have been better to interact with osx.  I will look more into bash.  Thank you for the pointer!  

I know its a kludge of a command.  :) though it was the first thing i could get to work :)  I appreciate the cleanup in code!

Is there a way to give all of you points?

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended to be a complete answer, because I'm not too familiar with the `security` command, although I beleive you'll need to preface it with the `sudo` command to modify the keychain. There's lots of good info on the Internet covering `security` command. I read quite a bit but there's nothing in my keychain I want to remove so I'm not able to test in this respect.

The following covers the `networksetup` command, which you may also need to use `sudo`, in Terminal, but in AppleScript add `with administrator privileges` at the end of the `do shell script` command", if necessary when preferred wireless networks.

It looks like your trying to remove all preferred wireless networks and this can be done directly in Terminal with the following command:

```
networksetup -removeallpreferredwirelessnetworks $(networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Wi-Fi/{getline; print $2}')
```

If you want to do the same thing in AppleScript, e.g:

```
do shell script "networksetup -removeallpreferredwirelessnetworks $(networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Wi-Fi/{getline; print $2}')"
```

If you want to use it in a bash script, then use the line above with a bash shebang, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
networksetup -removeallpreferredwirelessnetworks $(networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Wi-Fi/{getline; print $2}')
```

Save it in a plain text file without an extension, and make it executable, e.g. `chmod u+x filename` where `filename` is whatever you saved it as.  Then to use it in Terminal, `./filename` or `/path/to/filename`, if it's not saved in a location defined within the `PATH` environment variable.

If your looking to do it just for specific networks, then instead of a line for each network, you can loop through a list. If you need help with that, let us know.